Trying to find name of this thriller/drama/romance film from early 2000's
Movie was about a woman who tries to escape from her life and abusive  controlling husband by emailing a man whom she ultimately falls for and starts a virtual relationship with. Or it was one sided, I don't remember much at all. I just remember she grew strong feelings for him and thinks of him all the time. But the whole movie revolves around emailing her virtual lover.
The movie starts off with the woman on a bus with intense but chill electronic music. And it ended the same way, I think she was on her way to meet her virtual lover, or she ultimately leaves her violent husband. Something like that.
It was an indie art house film of some sort and I've watched it late at night a long time ago. Must have been around 2008, 2009... so this movie must've been from the early 2000's.
Country: USA
Language: English

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification.  What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title
